# Is there any way to insert multiple data in a field of table and one specific data has different value on its field? Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am making a quiz app and one question must be correct. I can already insert multiple data in my table, the problem that i have is, I have a one specific choice or answer that must be different from the others.

A screenshot of the app and what im trying to do

[image]

Here's what my table looks like

`table answers`

```
id | answer | correct
 1 |  Apple |     1
 2 |  Mango |     0
 3 |  Melon |     0
```

> 1, indicate for correct answer and 0 indicate for incorrect.

So here is my Model.

> I tried to make an attempt to fetch the radio button value which is the **`1` value** and insert it to the database but the result was, **IF I add another data** or multiple data. Index 0 or the first data was the only data that can be inserted. I **CANNOT** choose what radio button i can check **only the FIRST button** I can check.

```
// Insert questions

    $field_question = array(
        'question'=>$this->input->post('question'),
    );

    $this->db->insert('questions', $field_question);

    // Insert Answers
    $data_answer = $this->input->post('choice[]');
    $data_is_correct = $this->input->post('checkChoice[]');


    $value = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($data_answer); $i++) {
        $value[$i] = array(
            'answer' => $data_answer[$i],
            'correct' => $data_is_correct[$i],
            'question_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
        );
    }


    $this->db->insert_batch('answers', $value);

    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

Problem of my table if I add 3 new data

```
id | answer | correct
 1 |  Apple |     1
 2 |  Mango |     0
 3 |  Melon |     0
* New 3 Data Inserted 
 4 | Orange |     1
 5 | Tomato |     0
 6 | Grapes |     0
```

> I cannot make`Tomato` or `Grapes` to be my answer or make it as value number 1 only Orange or the first added data.

**VIEW**

So here is my radio button

```
<div class="form-check">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice[]" id="checkChoice" value="1" checked  />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Make this as an Answer
    </label>
</div>
```

And my form.

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/addQuestion">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Question</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Question" name="question" id="question" class="form-control" required />
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <h5>Create Choices: </h5>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                    <tr>  

                                         <td><input type="hidden" name="choiceHid[]" value="0" /></td> 
                                         <td><input type="text" name="choice[]" id="choice" placeholder="Enter your Choice" class="form-control" /> </td>  
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><span class="iconify" data-icon="ant-design:plus-circle-outlined" data-inline="false"></span> Add Response </button></td>  
                                         <td>
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice[]" id="checkChoice" value="1" checked  />
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                                        Make this as an Answer
                                                    </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>  

                               </table>  
                          </div>  
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    <input type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-block btn-info" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

> Script

```
<script>

    $('#btnSave').click(function(){
            var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
            var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
            //validate form

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response.success){
                            $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                            if(response.type=='add'){
                                var type = 'added'
                            }
                            swal("Success!", "You created a Question!", "success");

                        }else{
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Could not add data');
                    }
                });
        });


</script>
```

Dynamic Field Script

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append(
               '<tr id="row'+i+'">'+
                 '<td><input type="hidden" name="choiceHid[]" value="0" /></td>'+
                 '<td><input type="text" name="choice[]" placeholder="Enter your Choice" class="form-control" /></td>'+
                 '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><span class="iconify" data-icon="dashicons:remove" data-inline="false"></span></button></td>'+
                 '<td>'+
                        '<div class="form-check">'+
                            '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice[]" id="checkChoice" value="1" />'+
                                    '<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">'+
                                        'Make this as an Answer'+
                                    '</label>'+
                        '</div>'+
                 '</td>'+
               '</tr>'
               );  

      });  

      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  

 });  
 </script>
```

Comment: add code for dynamic_field addition...

Comment: @Antony Jack - pretty mucg the same, I think that dynamic field addition will not help. Its just a jquery and has the same name of the form.

Comment: what is the **value** in dynamic_fied radio button you added...

Comment: @Antony Jack - `<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice[]" id="checkChoice" value="1" checked  />`

Comment: you must need to set different values for radio button...

Comment: @Antony Jack - can you please provide some codes?

Comment: share your dynamic field addition code...

Comment: @AntonyJack - I added the dynamic field above sir, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Field Script

make variable **val** as a value of checkChoice like following...

```
  <script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  
          var i=1;  
          $('#add').click(function(){  
               var val =i;
               i++;  
               $('#dynamic_field').append(
                   '<tr id="row'+i+'">'+
                     '<td><input type="hidden" name="choiceHid[]" value="0" /></td>'+
                     '<td><input type="text" name="choice[]" placeholder="Enter your Choice" class="form-control" /></td>'+
                     '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><span class="iconify" data-icon="dashicons:remove" data-inline="false"></span></button></td>'+
                     '<td>'+
                            '<div class="form-check">'+
                                '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice" id="checkChoice" value="'+val+'" />'+
                                        '<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">'+
                                            'Make this as an Answer'+
                                        '</label>'+
                            '</div>'+
                     '</td>'+
                   '</tr>'
                   );  

          });  

          $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
               var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
               $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
          });  

     });  
     </script>
```

**View**

asign initial value of checkChoice as 0 like following

```
<div class="form-check">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="checkChoice" id="checkChoice" value="0" checked  />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Make this as an Answer
    </label>
</div>
```

**// Insert Answers**

```
$data_answer = $this->input->post('choice[]');
$data_is_correct = $this->input->post('checkChoice');


$value = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($data_answer); $i++) {

          if($data_is_correct == $i) {
            $correct = 1;
          } else {
            $correct = 0;
          }
    $value[$i] = array(
        'answer' => $data_answer[$i],
        'correct' => $correct,
        'question_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
    );
}
```

Comment: `$this->input->post('choice[]')`? are you sure about that?  Did you test?  Not sure I've ever used that syntax.

Comment: @AntonyJack - hello, I tried there's no error or any problems but the value of 1 is not inserted into any of the data I inserted. how's that sir? thanks!!

Comment: `print_r($data_is_correct);` in // Insert Answers, then check the values changed based on radio button or not

Comment: in my side its work perfectly...
be sure the updated version of answer...

Comment: @AntonyJack - it does insert values yes, but the choose `correct` value on the field is still 0, it needs to be one.

Comment: inspect and check the dynamic_fields values added by increament or not... like 0 ,1 ,2,3

Comment: @Antony Jack - yes it does increment the value but I only need the value to stick into 1. It does not need to be incremented. I just need to insert that value into the database and the current code does not do that. Thank you !

Comment: the incremented value is used to get the index of checkChoice...
then it's matched in controller, if matched then it become 1 else 0...

Comment: @AntonyJack - okay.. it does insert the value, now the last problem is the radio buttons, because I can choose TWO radio buttons. I need to choose only 1 radio button. THANKS!

Comment: @mickmackusa he not yet used that id often... may be here after he will use for validation or something, then he will increment that id as well as value...

Comment: You should fix your answer.